# Change expanded code from use double quotes to single quote

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working with React on intellij 15 if I write

```
.row>.col-log
<-- expands to -->
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-lg"></div>
</div>
```

it's ok but I'm using single quotes (`'`) for my project

I want to be expanded as

```
<div className='row'>
  <div className='col-lg'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it too much of a pain to try some [code templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/file-and-code-templates.html) instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that IntelliJ doesn't provide configuration for this approach. This is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25966145/2650174) but answers are not you looking for.

---

It will be much more easy to use [Replace in the current file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html?origin=old_help#2) (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) feature.

Also you can apply *replace* to full project only for particular files in particular folder using [Finding and Replacing Text in Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html?origin=old_help).